# Is there something I dont get about classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I´m creating a game from my childhood, and i want to have 2 players, each with a different set of cards and card colors.

I have tried to take it outside of the class and write some spaghetti code, didnt really work.

```
import random,time

cardOnTable = 1

cardOnTableColor = 'koule'

possibleColors = ['koule', 'srdce', 'listy', 'žaludy']

class Player:

    cardsInHands = []

    cardsInHandsColors = []

p1=Player()
print("Player 1 initialized")
p2=Player()
print("Player 2 initialized")

def giveCards(player):
    for i in range(4):
        player.cardsInHands.append(random.randint(1,10))
        player.cardsInHandsColors.append(random.choice(possibleColors))
        time.sleep(0.1)

giveCards(p1)
print(p1.cardsInHands)
giveCards(p2)
print(p2.cardsInHands)
```

**Expected output -:** `[3,2,2,2]` and `[9,10,5,8]`

**Actual output -:** `[3,2,2,2]` and `[3, 2, 2, 2, 9, 10, 5, 8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have setup `cardsInHands` and `cardsInHandsColors` as class variables instead of instance variables.  So they are shared among all instances of the class.  You should define them within the `__init__` method.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cardsInHands = []
        self.cardsInHandsColors = []
```

Answer (score -1):

you are setting global vars / local vars, you need to contain them in the class

```py
cardOnTableColor = 'koule'

possibleColors = ['koule', 'srdce', 'listy', 'žaludy']

class Player:
    def __init__(self,cards=[],colors=[]):
        self.cardsInHands = cards
        self.cardsInHandsColors = colors

p1=Player()
print("Player 1 initialized")
p2=Player()
print("Player 2 initialized")

def giveCards(player):
    for i in range(4):
        player.cardsInHands.append(random.randint(1,10))
        player.cardsInHandsColors.append(random.choice(possibleColors))
        time.sleep(0.1)

giveCards(p1)
print(p1.cardsInHands)
giveCards(p2)
print(p2.cardsInHands)
```

Did not test.

Comment: This has a similar problem to the OP, as your default argument lists are shared by all instances, and so will not always remain empty.